# DEA problem in GAMS

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I've written some codes in order to optimize a DEA problem using GAMS. After solving it, all the DMUs efficiencies were equal to 1.
As my GAMS program is Demo; therefore, I guess this may cause due to the higher number of digits (more than 7). I ran my codes with 2, three, four, and five digits, and I found out that for five digits and more, all DMUs will be completely efficient (=1). It seems that the software assumes the upper bound for data. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Welcome to OR SE. It is not clear what you mean by "digits" here. Can you edit your question to explain what you mean, and perhaps include data for a small example where not all DMUs should be efficient?

Comment: @Sara, welcome to OR.SE. As far as I know, the GAMS features are fully available in the demo version and it is just limited on the number of variables or constraints based on the problem one would like to solve.  Are you sure correctly formulating your problem?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.